# How to add 2 wile loop

Tags: mysql

I want to combined 2 database with 2 while loop. The codes are given below.

```
            <?php
               $query1=mysql_query("SELECT `a_id`,`a_name` FROM `photo_album`");

               while ($run=mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
                    $album_id  =$run['id'];
                    $album_name=$run['name'];

                $query2= mysql_query("SELECT `url` FROM `photo_gal` WHERE `album_id`='$album_id'");
                $run1  = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
                $pic   = $run1['url'];  

                while($ft=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            ?>
```

Comment: Why you want to use two database driver, mysql and mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

First comment: **use PDO or MySQLI**

**But to get your current code working:**

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT `a_id`,`a_name` FROM `photo_album`");
while ($run1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){

    $album_id = $run1['id'];
    $album_name = $run1['name'];

    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT `url` FROM `photo_gal` WHERE `album_id`='$album_id'");

    while($run2=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
         $pic = $run2['url'];
    }
}
```